# What metals can be extracted from what items?

Tags: mount-and-blade-bannerlord

I'm currently playing through Mount And Blade 2: Bannerlord, which has an interesting smithing system. whenever I visit a new settlement there is a trader who'll sell items and at times it's worth buying weapons with the intention of smelting these to materials.

I've been looking about but I'm unable to find a list of weapons/items and what exactly they smelt into. All items smelt into a set amount of materials, but is anyone able to tell me what all items will smelt into?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The list of items is very large, so I won't go into detail for it.

However, you can look at the weapon "tier" as a guideline for their most valuable result from smelting. It's not a fixed rule, but if your aim is to get the highest tier materials, you don't even need to waste your time with tier 4 or below items, probably not even with tier 5.

For Axes and spears, there will always be some hardwood component as well.

Tier 1: Crude Iron
Tier 2: Wrought Iron
Tier 3: Iron
Tier 4: Steel
Tier 5: Fine Steel
Tier 6: Thamaskene Steel

Comment: The idea of looking at tiers makes sense actually when I originally asked the question I was pretty new to the game and wasn't even aware of them - I would, however, add that not all T6 items give Thamaskene for example but it's a good general rule so I'll accept

Comment: One thing to add though, for certain items like wooden hammer and pitchfork, its worth 'smelting' them down to 3 hardwood a piece, which can be refined into 2 coal with the coal refiner perk, thus 1 net coal without having to expend anything other than stamina (use a low smithing follower to smelt).

Answer (score 1):

Pugio from Empire towns have the best value in terms of smelting.  They break down into 1 fine steel, 1 steel, 1 iron, and 2 wrought iron.  Sadly, they become hard to find after a while.